# Create a module to get taxonomy terms list

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Can someone please explain to me how i can to retrieve the taxonomy terms of a specific vocabulary step by step ? i saw many answers and code but since i'm new to drupal i don't know where the code should be in the module that i created to retrieve the taxonomy terms.